# Dynamically Add and Remove PHP Form fields from form (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm having some issues with the code that i wrote up to add and remove fields to a form. I currently have a jquery script that is working on another group of fields that require the same functionality, but for some reason this second Jquery i have set up is only adding the fields and not removing them here is the code.

HTML:

```
                <label for="EmergeContactType">Emergency Contacts</label>
      <hr>
    <div class="addcon">
        <p>
        <label for="EmergeContactType">Affilation</label>
          <select name="properties[EmergContactType]">
                    <option value="1">Primary</option>
                    <option value="2">Secondary</option>
                    <option value="3">Doctor</option>
                    <option value="4">Aunt</option>
                    <option value="5">Uncle</option>
                    <option value="1">Babysitter</option>
                    <option value="2">Caregiver</option>
                    <option value="3">Grandmother</option>
                    <option value="4">Grandfather</option>
                    <option value="5">Step-mother</option>
                    <option value="5">Step-father</option>
                  </select><br>   
    <label for="EmergeContactType">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" size="20" class="emerg" name="properties[EmergencyName]" align="right"  /><br>

  <label for="EmergeContactType">Number</label><br>
  <input type="text" width="15" maxlength="15" class="emerg" name="properties[EmergContactNum]" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" align="right"/><br>
</p>
    </div>

      <a href="#" class="addContact">Add Contact</a>
```

Script:

```
        $(function() {
var plusDiv = $('#addcon');
var y = $('#addcon p').size() + 1;


$('#addContact').on('click', function() {
$('<p>'+   
            '<label for="EmergeContactType">Affilation</label>'+
              '<select name="properties[EmergContactType'+ y +']">'+
                        '<option value="1">Primary</option>'+
                        '<option value="2">Secondary</option>'+
                        '<option value="3">Doctor</option>'+
                        '<option value="4">Aunt</option>'+
                        '<option value="5">Uncle</option>'+
                        '<option value="1">Babysitter</option>'+
                        '<option value="2">Caregiver</option>'+
                        '<option value="3">Grandmother</option>'+
                        '<option value="4">Grandfather</option>'+
                        '<option value="5">Step-mother</option>'+
                        '<option value="5">Step-father</option>'+
                      '</select><br>'+  
   '<label for="EmergeContactType">Name</label><br>'+  
        '<input type="text" id="EmergencyName" class="textbox" name="properties[EmergencyName'+ y +']" /><br>'+
 '<label for="EmergeContactType">Number</label><br>'+
      '<input type="text" id="EmergContactNum" class="textbox" name="properties[EmergContactNum'+ y +']" /><br>'+
           '<a href="#" class="remCon">Remove Contact</a></p>').appendTo(plusDiv);
y++;

return false;
});

plusDiv.on('click', '.remCon', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        y--;
}
return false;
});
});
```

JFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4SVXt/23/

Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont u are use `append()`;

Comment: your link may be wrong

Comment: That's the wrong JSFiddle link.

Comment: Sorry here is te correct link http://jsfiddle.net/propermike/1vp04r2b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling to remove the parent `p` of `#addcon`. You don't have an element with that id, hence no parent `p` so nothing gets removed in this statement: `$(this).parents('p').remove();`

**EDIT :**
[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/1vp04r2b/2/)
I felt like your code was a little heavy so I made some changes that should make this more efficient. Instead of rewriting the form in the code we just `clone()` it, then append the form to the `div` containing the forms. We then assign a remove button to each form that will remove its own form. The code is shorter and much more portable.

```
$('.addContact').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clonedForm = $('form[name="add_contact"]:first').clone(); // clone the form
    $('.addcon').append(clonedForm); // append the form to the div
    var removeLink = '<a href="#" class="removeContact">Remove Contact</a>'; // create a remove link
    $('form[name="add_contact"]:last').append(removeLink);
});
$('.addcon').on('click', '.removeContact', function(e) { // use on() to delegate
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').remove();
});
```

References:[`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So would changing the <div class="addcon"> to <div id="addcon"> be the correct way of resolving this?

Comment: No - whether it is an id or class doesn't matter at this point because there is no parent `p`. I am working on modifying your code.

Comment: Updated my answer @user3225090. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This looks good, I agree with you that the code was a bit heavy. One thing that i am concerned with is that these fields are just a part of more form fields that also get submitted. From reading your code I see that it will replicate the form but I am only looking to create more contact fields and not the whole form.

Comment: It would just be a matter of selecting / cloning the right elements. BTW, if this answer works for you please accept it.

Comment: Would adding a counter to this code be any different then what i had in the original code to distinguish the difference between fields that are added?